# How can I determine the layer name in an edit session?

Tags: arcobjects, editing, add-in, standard-license-level

I have a problem with an editor extension in an Add-In for ArcGIS 10.
The editor extension listens on different events occuring on shapefile layers via registering listeners:

```
mEditEvents.OnChangeFeature += OnChangeFeature;
mEditEvents.OnCreateFeature += OnCreateFeature;
mEditEvents.OnDeleteFeature += OnDeleteFeature;
```

All these callbacks get are a parameter of type IObject, which can be cast to IFeature.
With this IFeature I can get the feature class and its alias name (IFeature.Class.AliasName) which seems to be the name of the shapefile associated with this feature, but I want the name of the layer associated with this feature which can be different from the shapefile's name.

Is there any way how to get this layer name?

Update:

I found a solution (see my comment below).

Comment: Can you assume all edits are occuring on the current editlayer [IEditLayers.CurrentLayer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/CurrentLayer_Property/0020000000q9000000/)?  Or do you have other code somewhere that edits/updates features in other layers (these will fire events too)?

Comment: I already tried this, but IEditLayers.CurrentLayer is null if you (1) start an edit session, (2) select a feature and (3) move it somewhere. But this event should also be related to the correct layer it will operate on.

Comment: Do you need to support the situation where a particular featureclass is referenced by multiple featurelayers?

Comment: No, I just have 5 layers having different names than the shapefiles being the source of these layers. When an edit event arrives, I only have an object of type IObject which can be cast to IFeature. Then I can obtain the FeatureClass and its AliasName, but not the name of the layer this object belongs to.

Comment: @geoSuleiman, Are the 5 layers loaded into ArcMap for the edit?

Comment: Not a 100% sure on this, but if edit is occuring in ArcMap you can loop through the loaded layers, get the layer name from ILayer.Name then query to IFeatureLayer>IFeatureClass.AliasName to check against.

Comment: I think this would also have solved my problem (I used IFeatureLayer.FeatureClass.AliasName).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a simple solution: Before starting the edit session I store the alias names for each of the layers (I can identify the layers by their names).

With this mapping I now can relate any single edit event to the right layer because I have the AliasName of the feature's FeatureClass.

Comment: layer name and featureclass' aliasname are not necessarily same..a user can simply rename a layer in TOC

Comment: I know - that's the source of the problem / my question! And that's why I keep a mapping from aliasname to name (as I know every shapefile is only loaded once this is correct).

Answer (score 2):

You may need to get the dataset's name from the feature first. Then you can loop all the layers in TOC and check if their dataset name matches the one obtained earlier. It would look something like below.

```cs
IFeature feature = //get the feature..;
IDataset featureDs = (IDataset)feature.Class;
IMap map = //get the map...;

for (int i = 0; i < map.LayerCount; i++)
{
    ILayer layer = map.get_Layer(i);
    if (layer is IFeatureLayer)
    {
        IFeatureClass layerFc = ((IFeatureLayer)layer).FeatureClass;
        IDataset layerDs = (IDataset)layerFc;

        if (layerDs.Name == featureDs.Name)
        {
            //print the layer name in TOC..
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(layer.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Need to recurse into grouplayers.  Also need to check to make sure layerFc is not null, or why not just check to see if layerFc == feature.Class (reference equivalency)?

Answer (score 0):

**IFeature:Table**

[**IDataset:Name**

You can use the IFeature:Table property. Table implements IDataset so you can get the name from the IDataset:Name property. Here is an example:

> Private Function GetPathFromFeature(ByVal pfeature As IFeature) As
>   System.String
>
> ```
> If pfeature Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
>
> Dim ptable As ITable = CType(pfeature.Table, ITable)
>
> If ptable Is Nothing OrElse Not (TypeOf ptable Is IDataset) Then
>     Return Nothing
> End If
>
> Dim dataset As IDataset = CType(ptable, IDataset) ' Explicit Cast
>
> Return (dataset.Workspace.PathName & "\" & dataset.Name)
> ```
>
> End Function

Comment: This gives the same result as the featureclass' aliasname - not the name of the layer the feature belongs to (when asking my question I hadn't thought of the fact that a shapefile can be loaded multiple times and this is likely the reason why you cannot get the layer's name from a feature(class) as there could be more than one layer associated with this featureclass).